# How to Trigger Datagridview.cellValidating manually?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datagridview

I am inserting few records in my Datagridview from another table, I want to call CellValidating event for every record I insert. Please help me out.

Here is my code

```
            m_Sqlstr = "Select Distinct RFID, Prod_Code, Lot_No From  ScanStk Where BatchNo = '" & strBatchno & "' "
            m_SqlCmd = New SqlCommand(m_Sqlstr, Con)
            Con.Open()
            RFIDReader = m_SqlCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

            With m_BindingsrcDetail
                    While RFIDReader.Read
                        .AddNew()
                        .Current("SR") = m_BindingsrcDetail.Count
                        .Current("LOT_NO") = RFIDReader("LOT_NO").ToString.Trim
                        .Current("PROD_CODE") = RFIDReader("PROD_CODE").ToString
                        .Current("QUANTITY") = 1
                        GrdDetails.BeginEdit(False)
                        GrdDetails.CurrentRow.Cells("Prod_code").Value = RFIDReader("PROD_CODE").ToString
                        GrdDetails.EndEdit()
                    End While
            End With
```

grddetails is the name of grid,
m_BindingsrcDetail is datasource for grdDetails

According to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529757/validate-datagridview-cells-for-data-read-from-file/14530181#14530181) , You should be able to force the validation trigger using BeginEdit and EndEdit. but its not happening.

I am fetching Product description, MRP and other details in cell validating. So it necessary to call it.

Comment: Similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/42476772/2122718

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to change the current cell and then go back to it. Give this a try. You may have to alter it, as it hasn't been tested.

```
 BeginEdit();
 DataGridViewCell currentCell = GrdDetails.CurrentRow.Cells("Prod_code");
 EndEdit();
 CurrentCell = null;
 CurrentCell = currentCell;
```

Comment: Note, a try/catch around `CurrentCell = null;` may be necessary to detect validation failures.